# Almacenar columna tabla Jquery

Tags: jquery

Actualmente almaceno los datos de una tabla en un arreglo, de siguiente forma , trayendo los td, de que forma puedo traer una columna en particular?

```
var datos = []; 

    $("#table1 td").each(function(index) {//No se como traer solo el nombre
      // alert($(this).text());
      datos.push($(this).text()); 
      console.log(datos);
    });

<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>    
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Actualmente retorno todos los datos de la tabla y solo necesito el nombre, 
De que forma puedo Traer solo la columna nombre ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

en tu selector para hacer el `.each()` puedes dejarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#table tbody tr')
```

estas indicando que vas a recorrer todos los elementos del cuerpo de la tabla, ahora para insertar la informacion en el arreglo hay que buscar el elemento `td` especialmente el primero

```
$(this).find('td:eq(0)').text()
```

tu código funcionando:

```js
var datos = [];

$("#table1 tbody tr").each(function(index) {
  datos.push($(this).find('td:eq(0)').text());
});

console.log(datos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Gracias justo lo que necesitaba saludos !

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar una forma de identificar que tus datos pertenecen a cierta columna, en este ejemplo utilizo una clase que se llama `columnaNombre` que la asigno a cada casilla de la tabla que esté justamente en la columna de Nombre:

```js
var datos = []; 
var datos2 = [];

$("#table1 .nombreColumna").each(function(index) {//No se como traer solo el nombre
  datos.push($(this).text()); 
});

$("#table1 .apellidoColumna").each(function(index) {//No se como traer solo el nombre
  datos2.push($(this).text()); 
});

console.log(datos);
console.log(datos2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='encabezadoNombre'>Nombre</th>
      <th class='encabezadoApellido'>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='nombreColumna'>Jorge</td>
      <td class='apellidoColumna'>Casas</td>    
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class='nombreColumna'>Juan</td>
      <td class='apellidoColumna'>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Incluso agregué también la clase `apellidoColumna` por si solo ocupas los datos de la columna apellido.

Answer (score 1):

Que tal si a todos quienes tienen nombre le colocas una clase "nombre"? y los apellido una clase "apellido"?

```js
var datosNombre = []; 
var datosApellido = []; 

$(".nombre").each(function() {
  datosNombre.push($(this).text()); 
});


$(".apellido").each(function() {
  datosApellido.push($(this).text()); 
});

function mostrar(){
  alert(datosNombre);
  alert(datosApellido);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" borde="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Nombre</th>
          <th>Apellido</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="nombre">Jorge</td>
          <td class="apellido">Casas</td>    
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td class="nombre">Juan</td>
          <td class="apellido">Perez</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    <button onclick="mostrar()">mostrar Arreglo</button>
```

Así puedes manejar de mejor manera tu arreglo, sabiendo cuales son nombres, y cuales son apellidos en caso de replicar también para apellido. La ventaja es que si el indice 1 de nombre sera "Juan", el indice 1 de apellido sera "Perez".

Si ejecutas mostrar, aparecerá que están ambos guardados c:

Espero que sea de ayuda :D

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias posibilidades:

- Poniendo un identificador a la columna que quieras traer e incluirlo en el selector.

```js
$(function() {
    var datos = []; 

    $("#table1 td.name").each(function(index) {
    
      datos.push($(this).text()); 
      
    });
    
    console.log(datos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="name">Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>    
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="name">Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- Utilizando selectores CSS

```js
$(function() {
    var datos = []; 

    $("#table1 td:first-child()").each(function(index) {
    
      datos.push($(this).text()); 
      
    });
    
    console.log(datos);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jorge</td>
      <td>Casas</td>    
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Juan</td>
      <td>Perez</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```